# chained select_related from many tables in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-select-related

Here I have the following models:

```
class GenericUserData(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   ....

class NormalSellerDetails(models.Model):
    userid = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,db_column='UserID', unique=True)  # from table user.
    mobileauthenticationenabled = models.IntegerField(db_column='MobileAuthenticationEnabled', default=0)  # Field name made lowercase.
   .....

class UserBan(models.Model):
    user_id =  models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,db_column='UserID', unique=True)  # from table user.
    from_date = models.DateField(null=False)
```

and I want to perform a select like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM genericuserdata, normalsellerdetails, userban 
WHERE genericuserdata.id = normalsellerdetails.UserID AND genericuserdata.id = userban.UserID
```

I also have there seializers:

```
class GenericUserRetrievalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GenericUserData    
        fields = [ "email", "first_name", 'last_name', 'is_seller', 'is_normal', 'is_emp', 'is_male', 'bdate']


class AccountNormalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userid = GenericUserRetrievalSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = NormalSellerDetails
        fields = ['mobileauthenticationenabled',
                'emailauthenticationenabled',
                'mobilephone',
                'profilepiclink',
                'userid',
                'userban'
                ]
```

I could link between GenericUserData, and NormalSellerDetails by doing so:

```
class NormalAccountList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AccountNormalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = NormalSellerDetails.objects.all().select_related('userid')
         return queryset
```

but I couldn't link between all three into one query, noting model NormalSellerDetails relates to GenericUserData which in turn has an inverse relation to UserBan

My question is:
1- how to do that link?

2- userban table has rows for users who only are banned, How do create an output field having true when a row exists, and False when row doesn't exist?

also I tried to link by doing so, but didn't work

```
class NormalAccountList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AccountNormalSerializer
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsEmpReadAllUsersOrPost]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset= NormalSellerDetails.objects.select_related('userid').select_related('userid__userban_set').all()
        
        return queryset

class AccountNormalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userid = GenericUserRetrievalSerializer(many=False)
    userban = UserBanSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = NormalSellerDetails
        fields = ['mobileauthenticationenabled',
                'emailauthenticationenabled',
                'mobilephone',
                'profilepiclink',
                'userid',
                'userban'
                ]
```

it was telling me " Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'userban_set'. Choices are: linkcounter, normalsellerdetails, permissions, userban"
and when I remove the keyword set it doesn't actually return anything from userban table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queryset should look something like this:

```
queryset = NormalSellerDetails.objects.select_related('userid', 'userid__userban').all()
```

Note here that as indicated by the error you get, `userban` is the field you'll look for and not `userban_set`.

Regarding your second question, in order to have a field indicating if user is banned or not, you can annotate this field on the queryset like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField


queryset = NormalSellerDetails.objects.select_related(
    'userid', 'userid__userban').all().annotate(
     is_banned=Case(
         When(userid__userban__isnull=False, then=True),
         default=False,
         output_field=BooleanField()
     )
)
```

You can then add this field in your serializer fields and it should appear in your API response.

Note here that ideally you should name your attribute in `NormalSellerDetails` model as `user` instead of `userid`. Of course, on the SQL level these relationships are by the foreign key which is essentially an ID, however, referring it as `user` means you're going to the user table and then doing something with the attributes within that table. This would make your Django code more readable.

Comment: Thanks Very much bro, I have been trying for like a week, all tutorials are like very basic queries. I don't know if I can do that on stackoverflow, but if you have any suggestion for an advanced django/rest_framework course, can you please suggest it?, I would be glad to study it.

Comment: Hey @john! I'm glad that it helped you. You can upvote the answers like this on SO if you find them useful.

Regarding the book, I'd recommend Two Scoops of Django, which lists a lot of best practices with Django. You should start with the Django girls tutorial and then can follow this book.